# group by with linq bind to repeater

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have this query:

```
 public static Object GetEventsByMonth()
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var eventsByMonth = (from e in db.Events
            group e by e.StartDate.Value.Month into g
                         select new { Month = g.Key});

    return eventsByMonth;
}
```

which is bound to a repeater:

```
rptMonth.DataSource = EventsQ.GetEventsByMonth();
    rptMonth.DataBind();
```

I cannot understand why it does not let me to show month:

```
<%# Eval("Month")%>
```

It says: `System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'Event' does not contain a property with the name 'Month'.`

I do not want to show directly a property of event but I want to show the month...

Can you please suggest a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an anonymous type outside of the method that creates it, which is probably why you're having this problem. Try to bind the repeater in the same method that creates the LINQ object:

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(); 

var eventsByMonth = from e in db.Events 
                    group e by e.StartDate.Value.Month into g 
                    select new 
                    { 
                        Month = g.Key
                    }; 

repeater1.DataSource = eventsByMonth;
repater1.DataBind();
```

What you can do is create a class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
}

var db = new DogDataContext(ConnectString);
var result = from e in db.Events 
             group e by e.StartDate.Value.Month into g
             select new SomeClass()
             {
                 Month = g.Key
             };

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault:

- I had another nested repeater inside this one and I was trying to access month in the child repeater which of course does not work.